# Is there an API that allows other languages to script Blender

Tags: scripting, external-applications

I'd like to use Squeak Smalltalk and take advantage of the dynamic IDE (which could be modified to handle Blender explicitly).

Answer (score 6):

Other languages support (than Python) is [considered as antifeature](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/AntiFeatures) for now:

> Supporting multiple languages is not something we're currently
> interested in.
>
> Embedding a language runtime has a significant maintenance overhead,
> so there would need to be very compelling reasons (besides developer
> preference) to add support for other languages or to move away from
> Python.

Comment: Thanks. It's unfortunate. I can do things in the Squeak IDE that are pretty much impossible with other IDEs, such as embed the IDE in a 3D object or embed 3D object handling in teh IDE via 3D widgets (or some combination thereof).

The classic example is a computer console in a 3D spaceship that is actually displaying a live Squeak image, via a live, interactive Squeak IDE.

The image shown in the computer consolte could be the one controlling the drawing of the spaceship, or it could be a remote image via VNC (whether connecting to localhost or to a server 10,000 miles away).

Comment: Personally I think it's overkill to include a language runtime every time you want to support a language. I mean, there must be a well defined interface between C++ and the Python in the first place. Why not simply expose that interface externally so that other languages can interact with it? Or, simply allow an external python interpreter to speak to Blender, surely easy to do, and then other languages can interface to python.

Answer (score 3):

Blender has Python API. Read about it [in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_overview.html). You can interact with Blender through it. It's not uncommon for Blender add-ons to use some other software that Blender interacts with through the API. In some cases, like for example V-ray or Octane render engines need to change Blender itself to work so they modify Blender's source code, that you can also do since Blender is open source and you get custom Blender versions with these render engines. You can find out more about developing Blender [here](https://www.blender.org/get-involved/developers/)

Answer (score 2):

There is not such an API.  The API that allows Blender to include a Python interpreter relies on Python being implemented so that it is easy to include but also requires an extensive Python specific set of APIs provided by the C++ code.

To use Squeak, which was not implemented to support being an imbedded interpreter, you would have to modify the Blender C++ code to provide a set of APIs allowing Squeak to interact with Blender's internals *and* you would have to modify Squeak, as you suggest

It is doable, but it would require extensive work.

Comment: It might be easy enough to create a shim between Squeak and the Python API.

My real question concerns: can blender display its live rendering in a window created by an external application?

One trivial way to do that in Squeak would be via VNC, but I don't know if VNC of the blender window is doable using Blender or if you must use OS-level VNC (which simply punts the problem and is silly as you're using VNC to send the contents of Blenders OS window back to an application in the same OS).